# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando generar un random para un sitio de pruebas pero veo que choca mi script con otros elementos por el metodo `.text` de la transacción y me arroja el error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined
```

¿Alguna sugerencia para solucionarlo?

```
// Random para imprimir el id de la transacción.
var middle = ['123','2345','3456','3456','5','67890','9877','89878','8989','1010',],
  sufix = ['Ab','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

  var random = function(){
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) 
};

var idTansaction =  'Order Id \n '+ middle[random()] + sufix[random()];


console.log("Transaccion numero = " + idTansaction);
document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[1].text = idTansaction;

  if (page[page.length-1] === success_page) {

      dataLayer.push({
        'event':'purchase',
          'ecommerce': {
            'purchase': {
                'actionField': {
                  'id': idTansaction, // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
                  'affiliation': 'Online Store',
                  'revenue': totalTransaccion, // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
                  'tax': tax,
                  'shipping': '',
                  'coupon': couponString
                },
               'products': cartItems
            }
          }
        });


      localStorage.clear();
  }
```

Comment: Hola Oscar, tienes que asegurarte de que exista el elemento `h2` que estás tratando de modificar. Al parecer `document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[1]` no existe. Tal vez solo necesites guardar el resultado en una variable y validar su existencia antes de continuar.

Comment: Tienes que mostrarnos el html para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Hola si efectivamente tuve que poner una validacion para el elemento. solo si existe lo imprimo sino no hace nada.. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Es porque los elementos H1..H6 no tienen el atributo text, en su lugar usa innerHTML

```js
var idTansaction = 123;
//No existe .text
document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].text = idTansaction;
//asignado con .innerHTML
document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[1].innerHTML = idTansaction;
```

```html
<h2>Titulo</h2>
<h2>Titulo</h2>
```

Comment: Gracias Era porque había paginas en las que on existía el elemento .. Saludos y muchas gracias por el comentario.